# How to release Hotfix with maven release plugin

Tags: java, maven, release, release-management, maven-release-plugin

I'm using the Maven release plugin to do my releases.  But I can't figure out how to get it to do a Hotfix release.
I'm getting the error
`You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list. -> [Help 1]`

The naming strategy I'm using is something like this (but I'm open to suggestions)

- 1.2.3 <== Normal release
- 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT <== SNAPSHOT release
- 1.2.3-4 <== Hotfix #4

I'm open to suggestions on the naming convention for Hotfixes.

But basically, we have version `1.2.3`, which has already been released.  I need to create a Hotfix, which I wanted to call `1.2.3-1`.  That's when I got the error complaining about not having a SNAPSHOT project.

Another issue is that I want to make sure that I don't create a new development release.  Since version `1.2.3` was already released, I already have a `1.2.4-SNAPSHOT`. So when creating a Hotfix, it shouldn't need to make any changes for development.  I just want to create a branch (based on the `1.2.3` tag) for the Hotfix

Comment: The best and simplest is the way as described in the answer.  The question is what is the problem in creating a new development version...because such hot fix release should be created by creating a branch first...

Comment: Yes, I realize that I need to create a branch from the tag, but for a Hotfix, one usually wouldn't create a Snapshot version first, would you?

Comment: Yes why not. Creating the branch which needs to have a different version which is a SNAPSHOT version.

Comment: The term *hotfix* does not have a single widely understood meaning, so it us unclear what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list.`

check your other model which hasn't depend the model `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT`

Answer (score 3):

You should have a `SNAPSHOT` version currently defined in the POM to use maven release plugin.

In your case, I would:

- checkout the tag `1.2.3`, create a new branch..
- update pom with version `1.2.3-1-SNAPSHOT`
- use maven release plugin to release a `1.2.3-1` version